# Capturar texto entre dois caracteres conhecidos

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Preciso pegar um texto qualquer e encontrar as palavras (ou frases) que estejam entre dois caracteres específicos **`{`** e **`}`**, nesse caso.

Eu consigo fazer isso capturando os delimitadores junto, usando a expressão `{(.*?)}`, mas preciso que a `string` venha sem os dois caracteres de limite (**`{}`**).

Coloquei a tag [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) mas aceito respostas que não usem regex.

Comment: Tente isso: [^\{(.*?)\}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solução em Regex:

- Com `{}`

  ```
  Regex r = new Regex(@"\{[^\}]+?\}");
  Match m = r.Match(text);
  ```
- Sem `{}`:

  ```
  Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=\{)[^\}]+?(?=\})");
  Match m = r.Match(text);
  ```

Veja no [.netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/41PWSj)

Comment: Esqueci de dizer que preciso que seja sem as chaves...

Answer (score 1):

A expressão:

```
([a-z0-9])+(?=\})
```